# Customize x-axis on ZingChart

Tags: javascript, visualization, zingchart

I'd like to draw a graph similar to this one using ZingChart:
[image: r-graph]

The best I could do until now was this:
[image: zing-graph]

Souce:

```
{ 
  "graphset": [{
    "type": "line",
    "series": [
        {
            "values":[[1,218.2], [2,121.7], [4,62.27], [8,34.37], [16,19.79], [20,16.52], [32,17.1], [40,16.11], [64,91.9]]
        }
    ],
    "scale-x":{
        "values":[1,2,4,8,16,20,32,40,64]
    }
  }]
}
```

How can I fix the position of the x-ticks to be the same as the x-values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to start by setting the `max-items` and `items-overlap` attributes in your `scale-x` object to force show all items along the scale.

```
"scale-x":{
    "max-items":9999, //forces all items 
    "items-overlap":true, //forces items (labels) to show even when overlapping
    /* Code truncated for brevity */
```

After that, set the `alpha` (transparency) to 0 in the `item` object and the `tick` object to hide all of the ticks and items. Enable only the items you want to show by configuring an object within the `rules` array in both `item` and `tick` to display the desired scale values.

```
"item":{
    "alpha":0,
    "rules":[
        {
           "rule":"%scale-value == 1 || %scale-value == 4 || %scale-value == 8 || %scale-value == 16 || %scale-value == 20 || %scale-value == 32 || %scale-value == 40 || %scale-value == 64",
           "alpha":1
        }
     ]
},
```

I'm a member of the ZingChart team. Please take a look at [this demo](http://demos.zingchart.com/view/6RM21FU4) and let me know if I can answer any more questions on how this works.